# scanline in vuforia/unity CloudReco sample

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I try to get each position of green potions in vuforia/uinity (Cloud Recog) code.
I searched in CloudRecoEventHandler.cs and other Qualcomm AR Scripts but failed.
I want to get or toast point's position value
please help me out!
(green point means the twinkle green light in scanline)

Comment: they don't expose this data but you can use charles proxy to see what points are being streamed and reverse engineer it that way